# Under which conditions this condition of normality of groups translates into normality of extensions

Tags: galois-theory

Let $E/K$ be a Galois extension and $H \leq Gal(E/K)=: G$ be a subgroup. Under which hypothesis is the following true: $H$ is normal in G if and only if $E^{H}/K$ is normal.

This looks similar to a known result of Galois theory: if $E/K$ is Galois, $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $F/K$ is normal. I realize that if $H$ is finite, then Artin's lemma is valid and you can use it to prove the iff on the first paragraph. I was asking if there is a precise condition, even if artificial.

I don't know any counterexamples to $H$ normal if and only if $E^H/K$ normal.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample when $H$ is not finite?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: I didn't abandon it. I don't have any counterexample

Comment: How come is off topic if is about galois theory

Comment: When someone asks you a question, and you don't answer, and asks you again, and you don't answer, that sure looks like abandonment. Anyway, welcome back.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit into the body of your question that you don't know of any counterexamples to $H$ normal if and only if $E^H/K$ normal.

Comment: Have you disappeared again?

Comment: Sorry I am not really thinking this problem it seems too hard-.

Comment: Sure, but it's not that hard to edit an important fact into the body of the question. Would you please do that?

Comment: Abandoned, again.

Comment: Ok, did the edit. I 've been studying algebraic topology and didn't really go back to Galois theory